# Android LifeCycle Methods

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm new to Android Development and I have a question:

In which method of the Android Activity LifeCycle must I put the event of Views, for example when I click a button what happens.

Would it be in `onCreate` or in `onResume` and why?

Comment: why this question get minus !!!!!!!

Comment: Because you didn't do your homework. Please don't rely on Stackoverflow for everything, first try to google the stuff and if you don't find good answers then come to stackoverflow for answers. Here you go read this -

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: I am not sure if this question is subject for such many downvotes - there are dozen of stupid questions that have positive scores. @MGCR7 is asking `what is the best method to set view action listeners and why`. It may seem silly to ask, but at the second glance it's not like that. Please score down stupid questions and really silly ones.

Comment: @Varundroid thanks for you, but this is not a homework, I work on project and I don't know in which method should I write my onclick events.

Comment: @MGCR7 There are two ways of handling onclick on button. First, implement onClickListener in your activity and second is create a new anonymous while setting button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener { }); . And onCreate() is a best method to hook all view onClick listeners.

Comment: @gunar I suspect that many people think that an up vote on a question is "me too".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most of the cases you should have that in `onCreate` because this method is called once and you probably want to set those actions listeners once. `onResume`, according to Activity life-cycle may be called several times, according to [Activity life cycle doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle), and you would set those action listeners again for no reason.

However, if you would like to have a customizable behavior for that action listener for each time your `Activity` becomes visible again, it may worth set your action listeners in `onResume`, but that would probably apply for a small set of controls and I guess that would be very rare.

Answer (score 1):

May this help you:

You should intialize your variables and write your onClick events in `onCreate()` Method because it is called prior to all the methods in the LifeCycle of Android and it is called once in LifeCycle..

For More information Refer this link: [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Go through this [**article**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

As you said in java we call the function in main method .

In android if java class **extends**  **activity** you can call the method in  **Any of the life cycle event of activity** , It depends on your need . For example if you want to call method when you get into activity follow this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)//To set up ui for activity

    getDispalay();
}

public void getDispalay(){
 //your actions
}
```

Aslo you can call methods in other life-cycles Read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html#Create)